# How to read a file and write in to another file using a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have a file which looks like this (file1.txt)

```
258.2222
```

I have to write this `file1.txt` value to another file. if there in no value in `file1.txt` then
it should print as "Passed".

this is what I tried

```
for final in $(cat file1.txt);do
if [ "$final" ];then
        echo $final  > file2.txt
else
        echo "Passed" > file2.txt
fi
done
```

this only works with 1 scenario. if there is no value in `file1.txt` then it is not writing as **"Passed"**

expected output:

if there is a value in `file1.txt`:

```
258.2222
```

if there is no value (empty) in `file1.txt`:

```
Passed
```

Can someone help me to figure out this? Thanks in advance!

Note: I am not allowed to use general purpose scripting language (JavaScript, Python etc).

Comment: *if there is no value in file1.txt* - does this mean file1.txt is empty or it does contain single newline character?

Comment: that is mean  file1.txt is empty

Comment: If there is no value in the file, then the loop is executed zero times.

Comment: Please don't multi-post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/718867/133219

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `file1.txt` contains something (its file size is non-zero), you want that something to go into `file2.txt`:

```bash
if [ -s file1.txt ]; then
    cp file1.txt file2.txt
fi
```

If `file1.txt` is *empty* (or missing), then you want a line saying `Passed` written to `file2.txt`:

```bash
if [ -s file1.txt ]; then
    cp file1.txt file2.txt
else
    echo Passed >file2.txt
fi
```

If you want to avoid creating `file2.txt` if `file1.txt` is missing:

```bash
if [ -s file1.txt ]; then
    cp file1.txt file2.txt
elif [ -e file1.txt ]; then
    echo Passed >file2.txt
fi
```

The `echo` is now only executed if the `-s` test fails (the file does not exist, or it is empty) and `-e` test succeeds (the file exists).

At no point do you actually have to read the data from the file in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

The line `for final in $(cat file1.txt); do` is always of questionable value.  It will munge whitespace, and is generally a bad idea.  Sometimes it has a place, but for the most part there are better ways to iterate over the contents of a file.  In your case, this is causing an issue because when the file is empty the loop is executed zero times.

It's not clear to me if you are trying to parse the value in some way, or filter it from other content.  If you just want to copy the full contents of the file or write "Passed" if the file is empty, you can do:

```
if test -s file1.txt; then
    cat file1.txt
else
    echo Passed
fi > file2.txt
```

or

```
if ! grep '[^ ]' file1.txt; then echo Passed; fi > file2.txt
```

The `test` command in the first case will succeed (return 0) if `file1.txt` exists and has some content.  Note that this may simply be whitespace; if the file having non-zero size is not sufficient for your needs, you may want to use the second solution where `grep` only succeeds if it matches at least one line that has a non-space character (which may be a tab!).  (But note that this grep will filter out lines that are only space!).  If the `test` or the `grep` returns non-zero (eg, the file is empty or there are no lines that contain non-whitespace), then "Passed" is written.  Either way, the output is redirected to `file2.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

> that is mean file1.txt is empty

Then I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way

```
awk 'END{print NR?$0:"Passed"}' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

Explanation: I use so called ternary operator condition`?`valueiftrue`:`valueiffalse for condition I use just `NR` (number row) which inside `END` is total number of rows processed, if `file1.txt` has one or more rows I `print` `$0` which inside `END` is last line of file, otherwise i.e. where there is 0 rows in file I `print` text `Passed`.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
awk '{print} END{if (!NR) print "Passed"}' file1.txt > file2.txt
```